# get labix.org/v2/mgo error The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection

Tags: go

I'm trying to run a `main.go` file [Here](https://github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/tree/master/episode5) , and it shows error

```
cannot find package "labix.org/v2/mgo" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\labix.org\v2\mgo (from $GOROOT)
    D:\MyFolder\go-in-5-minutes\episode5\src\labix.org\v2\mgo (from $GOPATH)
cannot find package "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\labix.org\v2\mgo\bson (from $GOROOT)
    D:\MyFolder\go-in-5-minutes\episode5\src\labix.org\v2\mgo\bson (from $GOPATH)
exit status 1     Process exiting with code: 1
```

so I try to execute

```
D:\MyFolder\go-in-5-minutes\episode5\> go get labix.org/v2/mgo
```

But then I got this error:

> cd .; bzr branch https://launchpad.net/mgo/v2 D:\MyFolder\go-i
>   n-5-minutes\episode5\src\labix.org\v2\mgo
>   bzr: ERROR: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.
>   package labix.org/v2/mgo: exit status 3

How to solve this problem and get `labix.org/v2/mgo` ?

Comment: I don't know what's up with bzr and launchpad, but I do know that the project moved to gopkg.in/mgo.v2.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @CeriseLimón can I ask how to know or is there common way to know this kind of move? because https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo AND http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2 Are all existing sites.

Comment: I learned about the move from this [blog post](https://blog.labix.org/2014/07/21/mgo-release-r2014-07-21-now-at-gopkg-in).  I do not know of a common way to discover this kind of move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I replace all the files using

```
import (
    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)
```

with

```
import{
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
}
```

and pass build and works!